# Inheritance - Which method will be invoked

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is the scenario. If I have following classes and interfaces

```
public interface Jobinfo {}

public interface SpecificJobinfo {}

public abstract class AbstractJob implements JobInfo{}

public class SpecificJob extends AbstractJob implements SpecificJobInfo{}

interface Service {
    execute(JobInfo);
    execute(SpecificJobInfo);
}

// implementing class

public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
    SpecificJob specificJob = new SpecificJob ();
    execute(specificJob);
}
```

which method will be invoked - the one with JobInfo or SpecificJobInfo.

Comment: Consider testing using a java compiler.  The answer is neither.  The reference to execute is ambiguous.

Comment: thanks dwB - i just tried and its giving a compilation error with ambiguous message. thanks.. i think i got what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are *applicable* (because SpecificJob implements both `JobInfo` and `SpecificJobInfo`) and *accessible* (i.e. they are not private methods in a superclass), the rule is that always the *most specific* method will be invoked.

In this case, there is no most specific method because `JobInfo` and `SpecificJobInfo` are unrelated types (both variants of the `execute` method are *maximally specific*). Therefore the method invocation is ambiguous, and a compile-time error occurs.

Quoting the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

Had `SpecificJobInfo` extended `JobInfo`, the ambiguity would have been avoided in favor of `execute(SpecificJobInfo)`.

Comment: Thanks Javier for explaining the reason. It really helped me to understand the basic.